# Virtualised Windows 11 under virt-manager (QEMU/KVM) can't find USB SSD storage drive

Tags: usb, qemu, linux-kvm, libvirt, virt-manager

My virtualised Windows 11 under virt-manager (QEMU / KVM ) can see the USB wireless mouse, but cannot see the USB SSD storage device.
I took a check from the inside of Windows 11, in Disk Management of Computer Management, but the SSD storage is definitely not recognised.
Looking for some help to sort that out.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you attached it to the VM by any means though?

Comment: It does not **see** the wireless mouse, your virtual machine viewer passes through mouse input events to your hypervisor, which passes it through to your VM via a virtual device driver. There is no connection between the VM and your physical mouse, otherwise you won't be able to use the mouse on your client machine anymore. (USB devices cannot be connected to two USB-hosts)

Answer (score 0):

One main selling point of a virtualized environment is that **it cannot access the hosts hardware by default**.

You need to specifically instruct your hypervisor to pass through a USB device to a VM. It simply cannot smell if you currently want to use your external HDD on your physical machine or in the virtual machine, and both simultaneously is not possible with USB or most other data buses.

`virt-manager` is easily capable of doing that.

### Instructions:

1. Go to your VMs settings:

[image]

2. Click add a device:

[image]

3. Select USB host device as a device type:

[image]

4. Select the device you want to passthrough to your VM and click Apply:

[image]

---

### Notes:

**You probably need to restart the VM to have the settings take effect.**

**You will not be able to access the same device on your host as long as it is passed through!**

---

### Thoughts:

The provided solution will only work if you have physical access to your hypervisor, which is not possible if it runs e.g. in a datacenter.

You might want to have a look into using [SPICE](https://www.spice-space.org/), as it is able to easily pass through USB devices from your client device to your VM over a network connection. This means that you can e.g. use a laptop to connect to a VM running on your desktop, then in virt-viewer select a USB device connected to your laptop that you want to passthrough to your VM, without it having a physical connection to the host running the VM.

You can then very easily and without restarting VM or host connect and disconnect devices from virt-manager.

Note that this can be relatively slow if the hypervisor runs in a different network and you connect to it via WAN.

Comment: For storage devices, it's mostly better to attach it via viostor/vioscsi. usb-host probably won't offer you good r/w performance.

Comment: @TomYan If you can confirm that this works with both UAS and BOT disks in combination with windows as a client, and also manage to provide instructions on how to do so for a newbie, feel free to add an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I tried the procedure explained. Under the "USB Host Device" section there is no reference to my USB device sensor, only webcam, Bluetooth and wireless. The USB storage can be found under "PCI host device", and there you can find all my USB ports. The problem is that when I add one of them, like the Tiger Lake-H 3.2 Host Controller and I start the VM after restarting virt-manager, there is a message saying "Error starting domain: unsupported configuration: host doesn't support passthrough of host PCI devices".
Any further help is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem just remove all spice usb's problem solved. Gpu Passthrough uses neither Virtio nor Spice, just remove anything that fall's in that category. Also make sure your boot selections are checked off.